# Error....should I be using switch instead? (JS)

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which I have to flag certain holidays throughout the year.  I have determined the specific holidays, however i am having trouble on the front end allowing for the proper message to render, and I feel as if there is a shorter way of doing this, but not sure.

My code below is here. This is written in a controller, and i am using coffeescript, but for the sake of this question, converted the coffee script into javascript.

```
day = new Date()
month1 = moment()
var date, holiday2, month, weeknum;
date = day.getDay();
month = month1.month() + 1;
weeknum = Math.ceil(date / 7) + 1;
holiday2 = month + "/" + weeknum + "/" + date;

if (holiday2 === "1/3/1") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Martin Luther King Day"; }
if (holiday2 === "2/3/1") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Washington's Birthday"; }
if (holiday2 === "5/3/6") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Armed Forces Day"; }
if (holiday2 === "9/1/1") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Labor Day"; }
if (holiday2 === "10/2/1") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Columbus Day"; }
if (holiday2 = "11/4/4") {
  vm.typedholiday = "Thanksgiving Day"; }
vm.message = true

.row.holiday-banner{ 'ng-if' => "vm.message" }
  .col-xs-12
    .holiday-body.text-center
      %h3 We are currently closed due to {{ vm.typedholiday }}.
```

So with this I have two questions. The date of me writing this question does actually happen to be Columbus Day.  However, I continue to have Thanksgiving Day rendered instead of Columbus Day.  I can't figure out why this is the case.  If there is something with my code that would cause that, please let me know. I am also wondering if it would it be better to use the JS 'switch' method instead? if so, how?

Comment: Shouldn't `holiday2` be an array of date->name? Then just perform an array lookup. No need for a long sequence of conditionals...

Comment: Just create an object: `{'1/3/1': 'Martin Luther Kind Day'}`. Then you can lookup straight from it.

Answer (score 3):

Your value is overwritten since your last `if` isn't using a comparison operator, it's using an assignment operator:

```
if (holiday2 = "11/4/4")
```

All this does is assign the string `"11/4/4"` to `holiday2` and since that is a truthy value, continues with the next statement which overrides `vm.typedholiday` with `"Thanksgiving Day"`.

The obvious fix is:

```
if (holiday2 === "11/4/4")
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been pounding out code for almost 10 hours today....after a while i don't always see my mistakes.

Comment: @kdweber89 the debugger does see a lot of things, and it helps you a lot. learn to use it. (And, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `switch` instead - it doesn't make much difference. If your project has a styleguide, do what that says. If not, choose the style you prefer.

If you did use `switch`, it'd look something like this:

```
switch (holiday2) {
  case "1/3/1":
    vm.typedholiday = "Martin Luther Kind Day";
    break;
  case "2/3/1":
    vm.typedholiday = "Washington's Birthday";
    break;
  // more cases
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider this :

```js
...
holiday2 = month + "/" + weeknum + "/" + date;

var specialDays = {
   "1/3/1"   : "Martin Luther Kind Day" ,
   "2/3/1"   : "Washington's Birthday" ,
   "5/3/6"   : "Armed Forces Day" ,
   "9/1/1"   : "Labor Day" ,
   "10/2/1"  : "Columbus Day" ,
   "11/4/4"  : "Thanksgiving Day" ,

}
vm.typedholiday = specialDays[ holiday2 ];

vm.message = true
...
```

I found this more readable, and easy to extend !